# Can't find path to the project on virtual machine running workflows

Tags: virtual-machine, github-actions

job execution on the VM .
When the job begins, GitHub automatically provisions a new VM for that job. All steps in the job execute on the VM, allowing the steps in that job to share information using the runner's filesystem. You can run workflows directly on the VM or in a Docker container. When the job has finished, the VM is automatically decommissioned.
I found this from https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners

I need to know the exact filepath to my project on github virtual machine.

For example:

```
name: Node Continuous Integration

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]


jobs:
  test_pull_request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
      - run: npm run build
```

I know that my project will be copied to ubuntu virtual machine but where exactly will it be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the checkout action, your repository files will be located under the `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` directory.

`$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` - a default environment variable that means the default working directory on the runner for steps, and the default location of your repository when using the checkout action. For example, `/home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name`.

For more details, see:

- [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v3) docs
- [Default environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) docs